# for-loop seems to only run once when it should run until certain value reached

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I have some code that i have displaying the correct information but the loop is only repeating once and I need to repeat until max is reached.

```
    double x, v, max = .092 * Volt;
    int t = 0, resistance = initialResistance, stop = 0;

    System.out.print("\t");
    for (int column = initialResistance -= 100; column < finalResistance;       column += 100) {
        System.out.print(resistance + " \t");
        if (resistance < finalResistance) {
            resistance += 100;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i <= t; i += 10) {
        System.out.print("t:");
for (int j = initialResistance -= 100; j < resistance; j += 100) {
            if (resistance < finalResistance) {
                resistance += 100;

            }

            while (stop != 1)
            {
              resistance = initialResistance;
              for (int r = initialResistance -= 100; r <= resistance; r += 100) {
                if (resistance >= finalResistance)
                    {
                    resistance = finalResistance;
                    }
                    x = -(t / (resistance * capacitorValue));
                    v = Volt * (1 - Math.pow(BASE, x));
                    if (v <= max)

                 System.out.print("\t"+ String.format("%.2f", v));
                else
                 System.out.print("");

                if (r >= resistance && v > max)
                {
                 stop = 1;
                }
                 resistance += 100;
                }
                t += 10;
                System.out.println("");

            }
        }
    }
```

500     600     700
t:  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
    0.92    0.77    0.67    0.67    0.67

t:t:t:

is the current display when 500 and 700 are the initial and final resistance and .25 is the capacticorValue

so it displays properly but needs to repeat more and i need to get rid of the extra 0.00 and .67 and figure out why it doesn't show "t:" on the second line

Comment: "[...] but the loop is only repeating once.[...]" You have multiple loops. Which loop are you talking about? Also, please format your code properly, especially if you have nested constructs.

Comment: I'm not sure which loop is the problem and how could I format it better?

Comment: Look at your indentation. Some parts within the innermost `while` are a little bit messy.

Comment: Is it right, that you always decrement `initialResistance` at the beginning of the for-loops, because you used the operator `-=` instead of simple substract.

Comment: I changed that but it doesn't do anything to change the code

Comment: @everGlade In which direction do you changed it, operator `=` or `-`?

Comment: ended up just taking the -=100 out

Comment: Ok, but the problem is, that `stop` is set during the first execution of the while loop. It remains set, so the while-loop is never executed again, see more in my answer.

Comment: It is not fair to remove the question. But anyway, it is visible through the edit history.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself. Do *not* erase your question, since the reason you can ask it here is so others can make use of it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `initialResitance - 100` is 100 smaller than `resistance` and if `j` (or `r`) is increasing by 100 every time it's `100 / 100 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

During the first iteration of the `j` loop, the inner `while(stop != 1)` loop is breaked with `stop = 1`. This flag variable remains set, when the second `j` iteration is started. The `while` loop is never entered again because `stop` is still 1.

Note, that reseting stop to '0' after the while loop doesn't help. The program will run indefinitely, because `t` is incremented in the inner loop so that for the `for(int i` loop will never stop.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to simplify your code.
- Structures like you have here (a for-loop in a while-loop in a for-loop in a for-loop) are enormously error-prone.
- Minimize variable changes, particular for loop-termination variables.  (You change the value of 'resistance' in 6 different places.)
- Don't introduce side-effects into loop definitions.  (If you want to decrement 'initialResistance' do it explicitly.)